# Smart Panel not populating with the correct values

Tags: acumatica

I have created a dialog box (smart panel) with a grid  on the Transfers screen (IN204000) which is supposed to be populated from the Request screen (RQ301000), and the line items of the transfers are populated with the selected items from the dialog panel. The issue is that I am not getting all the values to show on the panel although when debugging the correct values are shown. I am expecting the panel to show 8 values but it only displays one as per screenshot one.
How can I correctly populate the panel from the requests and then the line items of the Transfers from the panel?

Screenshot 1:
[image]

code snippet:

```
        [PXVirtualDAC]
        public SelectFrom<CurrRequests>.View PopulateRequestsView;
                                                                   
                                                                   

        public PXSelect<RQRequest, Where<RQRequestExt.usrWarehouse, Equal<Current<INRegister.toSiteID>>>> Requests;

    
        public PXAction<PX.Objects.IN.INRegister> PopulateRequests;
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Populate Requests")]
       
        protected virtual IEnumerable populateRequests(PXAdapter adapter)
        {

            PopulateRequestsView.Cache.AllowInsert = true;
            PopulateRequestsView.Cache.AllowUpdate = true;
            PopulateRequestsView.Cache.AllowDelete = true;

            INRegister iNRegister = Base.transfer.Current;

            PXResultset<RQRequestLine> rQRequestLines = PXSelectJoin<RQRequestLine,
                LeftJoin<RQRequest, On<RQRequest.orderNbr, Equal<RQRequestLine.orderNbr>>>,
                Where<RQRequestExt.usrWarehouse, Equal<Required<RQRequestExt.usrWarehouse>>>>
                .Select(Base, iNRegister.ToSiteID);


            foreach (RQRequestLine Reqs in rQRequestLines)
            {
                
                CurrRequests lineItem = new CurrRequests();

                lineItem.Selected = false;
                lineItem.InventoryID = Reqs.InventoryID;
                //lineItem.InventoryID = Convert.ToInt32(inventoryItem.InventoryID);
                lineItem.Qty = Reqs.OrderQty;
                lineItem.ReqNum = Reqs.OrderNbr;
                lineItem.ReqDate = Reqs.RequestedDate;

               this.PopulateRequestsView.Insert(lineItem);
           

            }

         


            if (PopulateRequestsView.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
            
            {

         
                foreach (CurrRequests rowitem in PopulateRequestsView.Select())
                {

                    if (rowitem.Selected.Value)
                    {

                        INTran iNTran = Base.transactions.Insert();
                        INTranExt iNTranExt = iNTran.GetExtension<INTranExt>();

                        iNTran.InventoryID = rowitem.InventoryID;
                        iNTran.Qty = rowitem.Qty;
                        iNTranExt.UsrRequestNumber = rowitem.ReqNum;
                        iNTran.TranDate = rowitem.ReqDate;

                        if (iNTran.InventoryID != null)
                        {
                            Base.transactions.Update(iNTran);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            Base.transactions.Delete(iNTran);
                        }
                       
                    }

                }


            }
            return adapter.Get();
        }
```

DAC for the panel fields:

```
[Serializable]
    [PXCacheName("CurrRequests")]
    [PXVirtual]
    public class CurrRequests : IBqlTable
    {
        #region LineNbr
        [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
        //[PXIdentity(IsKey = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "LineNbr")]
        public virtual int? LineNbr { get; set; }
        public abstract class lineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<lineNbr> { }
        #endregion

        #region Selected
        [PXDBBool()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
        public virtual bool? Selected { get; set; }
        public abstract class selected : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<selected> { }
        #endregion

        #region InventoryID
        [PXDBInt()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
        public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
        public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<inventoryID> { }
        #endregion

        #region Qty
        [PXDBDecimal()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Qty")]
        public virtual Decimal? Qty { get; set; }
        public abstract class qty : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<qty> { }
        #endregion

        #region ReqNum
        [PXDBString(255, InputMask = "")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Req Num")]
        public virtual string ReqNum { get; set; }
        public abstract class reqNum : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<reqNum> { }
        #endregion

        #region ReqDate
        [PXDBDate()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Req Date")]
        public virtual DateTime? ReqDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class reqDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<reqDate> { }
        #endregion
    }
```